# ESXi 5.5 Isolate Network

Tags: security, firewall, vmware-esxi, router, isolated-network

I have recently acquired a poweredge running esxi 5.5, and am creating a network for pentesting purposes. Currently my main network and the pentesting network are entirely seperate entities, having no connection whatsoever. the main network is running in 192.168.1.0/24 and the pentest network will be assigned 10.0.0.0/27.

I would like to connect the pentest network (read: vulnerable) to the internet for external tests, but this requires sharing a router with the main network.

how can i isolate these two so that both receive internet but there is no possibility of talk between 192.168.x.x and 10.x.x.x? This network will be moderately to very vulnerable and an easy target. I would like to do everything to minimize any bleed over into the real network.

UPDATE:
So currently the pentest network is a single ESXi and 2 laptops connected to a linksys soho router. No VLANS, no fancyness. just a poweredge plugged into a soho router. Although plans to upgrade the router will happen eventually, Im not concerned with that right now. this network is connected to nothing else.

the main network is a ddwrt soho router connecting 2 workstations, a media server and an unknown number (average 5) wireless devices, and connected to the internet. Your basic 192.168.1.0/24 home network with NAT.

more routers, firewalls, IDS, anything can be purchased/virtualized as nessesary for security, budget and time are not a problem right now, but so far its a standard setup.

Comment: Have a VLAN maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is almost nothing to do with being on an ESXi host - it's a routing issue - you just need two separate VLAN coming from your router, both of which have external routes out and no routing between them. Then simply trunk these VLANs to your ESXi uplinks and create two VLAN tagged port groups in you vSwitch/es. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some information about your networking setup. How is the ESXi server attached to the network? How do you route your network? What kind of Internet Uplink do you have and how is it connected to your network? Do you work with VLANs? What kind of Networks have you created to attach the VMs to?

Both your networks are private, so you need some kind of routing to access the internet. You could simply decide to not route between the two networks on your router which would prevent talking from one network to the other, which i guess is the case.